# Error constructing Array1D

Tags: javascript, node-red, deeplearn.js

I am trying to start learning machine learning using deeplearn.js in node-red.

To start with this I created the simple `Inject>Function>Debug` node flow, imported the library and copied the [Getting Started](https://deeplearnjs.org/#getting-started) example with edits to work within node-red.
This looks like this:

```
dl = global.get('dl');
const math = dl.ENV.math;

const a = dl.Array1D.new([1,2,3]);
//const a = dl.Scalar.new(2);
const b = dl.Scalar.new(2);

const result = math.add(a, b);
return {payload: result.dataSync()};
```

the problem ist that `dl.Array1D.new([1,2,3]);` throws

> Error: Error constructing Array1D. Shape of values  is not 1 dimensional.

If "a" is a Scalar or Array2D everything works fine.
Does someone has an idea where this Array is not 1 dimensional or how to force it to be?

Comment: can you pass mutiple params? `dl.Array1D.new(1,2,3)` Try it maybe?

Comment: @CristianS. multiple parameters do not work.
@ChrisG I am using `Array1D.new` [link](https://deeplearnjs.org/docs/api/classes/array1d.html#new) `dtype` is optional here. But after your hint I tryed `new dl.Array1D([4,1], 'float32', [1,2,3,4]);` instead and this works. But it seems very unconventional I think.